# How i can operate with http.get in cycle

Tags: http, node.js

I need in cycle create http.get request to google api|cache service. With nodejs i try do it

```
for(var i = 41923,postID=i; i <= 41925; i++) {

    http.get(options, function(res) {
                res.setEncoding('utf8');
                res.on('data', function(data) {
                    responseBody += data;
                }).on('end', function() {
                    if(getPostCacheUrl) {
                        var json = JSON.parse(responseBody);
                        json.items = json.items || [];
                        var cacheUrl = getPostCacheUrl(json);
                        parseCacheUrl(cacheUrl);
                    }
                }).on('error', function(error) {
                    console.log('ERROR' + error.message);
                });

    });
}
```

But i catch error:

```
undefined:1
: 200}{"response
      ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at Object.parse (native)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/Users/macbookpro/Sites/googlecache/title.js:30:41)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:88:20)
    at HTTPParser.onMessageComplete (http.js:137:23)
    at Socket.ondata (http.js:1137:24)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:354:27)
```

Comment: First of all, why would you do such a thing. http.get in a cycle till 41923?! Bad Idea...
Anyway, this seems like a json-parsing error, check the string which google responds if it's valid or not

Comment: And if have to mention, that you extend your body with each cycle. clear your responseBody before you step into the http.get

Comment: change my code to for(var i = 41924,postID=i; i <= 41925; i++) {
    responseBody = '';
but still same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all it looks like you are not getting any data... in line

```
}).on('end', function() {
```

there should be a handler from which you take response and parse it, eg:

```
}).on('end', function(responseBody) {
```

Add console.log(responseBody) to check if it's an object, I don't remember what is passed in here.

I will not ask why you need to request so many data from google (watch out for the ban or anti spam actions) ;)

The other problem from what I can see here may be asynchronous requests. Please try below and let me know if it helped. It will wait for finish of request before sending next one. I'm guessing that is the problem.

```
function getSomething(i) {
    // make sure that i is int
    i = parseInt(i);

    console.log('Getting something: ' + i);

    // put the i somewhere if needed... not sure what you need...

    // break if out of the scope
    if (i < 41923 || i > 41925) return;

    http.get(options, function(res) {
                res.setEncoding('utf8');
                res.on('data', function(data) {
                    responseBody += data;
                }).on('end', function(responseBody) {
                    // Do console.log(responseBody) to check how the response looks, it is probably object - pass data from it to JSON.parse()
                    // Not sure what is this var getPostCacheUrl
                    if(getPostCacheUrl) {
                        var json = JSON.parse(responseBody);
                        json.items = json.items || [];
                        var cacheUrl = getPostCacheUrl(json);
                        parseCacheUrl(cacheUrl);
                    }
                    console.log('Getting something: success - triggering next get!');
                    getSomething(i + 1);
                }).on('error', function(error) {
                    console.log('ERROR' + error.message);
                    // If you need to go on even if there is an error add below line
                    //getSomething(i + 1);
                });
                // I would suggest to check timeout even as well    
    });
}
getSomething(41923);
```

The example can be checked here http://jsfiddle.net/Pu3cr/2/ but it will not work because of obvious reasons. I hope that it will help you with your project.

Please let me know if you need anything more.

Best,
Marek

Comment: There is no problem with the for-cycle, the problem is, that you have to handle to content inside right. The problem lies in the JSON-parser, which means that there is a problem with the passed string.

Using the on.data only makes sense, if you can work with these chunks in a special way, on.end should be enough here